# Нужна помощь с TabLayout

Tags: java, android

Сделал TabLayout в стиле Material Design: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть 12 `EditText`, мне нужно независимо в какой `EditText` я напишу число, оно должно появиться сразу во всех других `EditText`, уточняю что именно у меня не получается (пример:мне надо например я ввел в первый edittext число а во втором edittext это число поделить на 2 и в 3 edittext поделит на 4 и так далее  )

// ***Converter***

```
public class Converter extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.converter);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter_converter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter_converter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment_converter(), "Метрические:");
        adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment_converter(), "Английские /Американские:");
        adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment_converter(), "Тройская система веса:");
        adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment_converter(), "Британская аптечная:");
        adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment_converter(), "Японские единицы веса:");
        adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment_converter(), "Китайские единицы веса:");
        adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment_converter(), "Старорусские меры веса:");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }
```

// ***ViewPagerAdapter_converter***

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter_converter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter_converter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
}
```

// ***PeopleFragment_converter***

```
public class PeopleFragment_converter extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.peoplefragment_converter, container, false);
    }
}
```

*вот что получилось но это не то что должно быть*

```
public class PeopleFragment_converter extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View viewPager = inflater.inflate(R.layout.peoplefragment_converter, container, false);

    final EditText editText1 = (EditText) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.a1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.a2);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.a3);
    EditText editText4 = (EditText) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.a4);
    final EditText [] editTexts = new EditText[] {editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4};
    final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {       }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
                if (!editText.hasFocus()) {
                    editText.setText(s);
                }
            }
        }
    };


    for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                EditText chosenEditText = (EditText)view;
                if (b) {
                    chosenEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                }
                else {
                    chosenEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                }
            }
        });
    }
return viewPager;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, у Вас здесь 2 вопроса: 1) как конвертировать вводимую величину для разных единиц измерения в рамках одного фрагмента; 2) как передавать данные из одного фрагмента в другой при листании ViewPager. Если это так, то сделайте 2 отдельных вопроса. Иначе нелогично, и неудобно отвечать, и неудобно пользоваться в дальнейшем другим пользователям. Мне кажется, я могу ответить на первый вопрос, если вы сделаете его именно таким (1).

Comment: @iramm изменил для первого варианта вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем упрощенный конвертер весов. Выглядит так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разметка:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ton"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ton_et"
            android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/centner"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/centner_et"
            android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/kilogram"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/kilogram_et"
            android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gram"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gram_et"
            android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Вот класс фрагмента (без импортов):

```
public class WeightConverterFragment extends Fragment{
private String LOG_TAG = "WeightConverterFragment";

// значение в тоннах, которое всегда обновляется при обновлении любого EditText
// Оно потом пересчитывается для всех EditText, которые не в фокусе
private double tonsValue;

// номер EditText, который находится в фокусе - нужен для расчета tonsValue
private int chosenIndex;

// таблица перевода тонн в тонны, центнеры, килограммы, граммы
private static final double [] convertRatiosFromTons = new double [] {1, 10, 1000, 1000000};

private  EditText [] editTexts;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weight_converter, null);

    EditText tonEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ton_et);
    final EditText centnerEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.centner_et);
    EditText kilogramEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.kilogram_et);
    EditText gramEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.gram_et);

    editTexts = new EditText[] {tonEditText, centnerEditText, kilogramEditText, gramEditText};

    for (EditText editText : editTexts) {

        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {

                EditText chosenEditText = (EditText)view;

                //определяем номер строки таблицы, в которой стоит chosenEditText
                TableRow currentTableRow = (TableRow) chosenEditText.getParent();
                TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) currentTableRow.getParent();
                int childCount = tableLayout.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    if (currentTableRow == tableLayout.getChildAt(i)) {
                        chosenIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (b) {
                    chosenEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                }
                else {
                    chosenEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return v;
}

private final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length; i++) {

            // Если пока цифр не набрано, выходим из метода раньше
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s))
                return;
            // записываем значение тонн
            double enteredValue = Double.valueOf(s.toString());
            tonsValue = enteredValue / convertRatiosFromTons[chosenIndex];
            // пересчитываем все поля, которые не в фокусу
            if (!editTexts[i].hasFocus()) {
                editTexts[i].setText(String.valueOf(tonsValue * convertRatiosFromTons[i]));
            }
        }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Великолепный ответ!